# Where's the place in MVC for ajax requests/data requests?

Tags: ios, ajax, design-patterns, model-view-controller, ios7

I started learning iOS development in the last days and I'm not sure how to organize the code.

Imagine a simple Blog Reader app, where we've to use an API to retrieve the most recents posts. I saw tutorials and source code where developers put the ajax call in the Controller. Shouldn't this be the responsibility of the Model?

For me it makes sense to create a Model class that it's responsible for:

- Making the ajax call
- Parsing the response data
- Updating the self.data_structure
- Notifying the Controller

How about data filtering and data manipulating, where does it belong according to MVC? By data manipulation I mean, quick example: `{"Price" : 12, "Amount" : 2}`, we can calculate the total amount and for it. It makes sense to store it in the Model instead of storing and calculating it in the Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tutorials don't exactly follow MVC strictly. It is ok to put those calls in the controller, but its not recommended and its usually put into a separate model class. The separate model class should call off the thread as well and its completionHandler should notify the controller using a NSNotification.

In my usual code, I have the call in a separate queue and its completion handler calls `[self parse Data]`, which parses the data *in* the separate queue. After the parsing is done, use a NSNotification to notify the controller to get the parsed contents from the model.

Data manipulation should be managed by the model as well, feed the model the NSDictionary and let the model return the calculated amount.

Comment: I also noticed that, in tutorials, some developers tend to get the data from the Model and create, usually, and NSArray to pass to a UITableView. Is it ok to use a Composite design pattern by setting a property in the Controller that points to the Model?

Comment: @schemetrical This model that you speak of, what class type is it?

Comment: @Mário Yes, you can create it to pass to the UITableView, but its generally done in the model to gather the data and making it into an array. The controller usually just takes the array and cycles it in the tableview.

Comment: @Pavan The model is a conceptual class, it is an implementation file but does not communicate directly to the view or the controller.

Comment: @Schemetrical oh ok, that's pretty cool, so its a bit like my `appConfig` file where I have methods that are called over and over again like my `table:viewForHeaderInSection:` method, but instead of putting only my recurring methods, I would also put my methods that take the webdata received and pass that into my 'model - my `appConfg file`' and the method in that should then return the array where I would then go about as normal and populate the table. At the moment I have all my data from webservice to meaningful array in their own files in their respective view controllers